# given continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ prove $\exists\delta>0$ s.t. $x\in B(c;\delta)$ $f(x)>m$

Tags: real-analysis

So for a homework assignment for a real analysis class I'm given the following:

Given a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and a point $c\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Then assume $0<m<f(c)$ with $m\in\mathbb{R}$. Show $\exists\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in B(c;\delta)$ the following holds: $f(x)>m$.

I worked out the following: Since $f$ is continuous, there must be a $\delta$ s.t $|x-c|<\delta$ for every $\epsilon$ s.t. $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$, so, using the triangle inequality, I see that: $\epsilon>|f(x)-f(c)|\geq|f(x)|-|f(c)|>|f(x)|-m>0$, meaning that $|f(x)|>m$ should hold then. I think it's alright what I've done, yet I can't shake that I'm still missing something, mainly because of the absolute value of $f(x)$. I would gladly take any help that I can get, thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't conclude $|f(x)| > m$ from what you have written

Comment: I realized this just now; even more so, when typing out I saw: $\epsilon>|f(x)-f(c)|\geq|f(c)|-|f(x)|>m-|f(x)|>0$ which actually says the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $|f(x) - a| < \varepsilon$ then $f(x) > a - \varepsilon$ so you can choose $\varepsilon = f(c) - m$ and then continue your proof

Comment: I made a typo in the question: I should show that $f(x)>m$ instead of $f(x)>0$.

Comment: I edited accordingly @static